# Button isn't clickable because of of a div overlay - possible z-index issue

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have the following markup at the moment: https://jsfiddle.net/axgetf94/

I'm looking to build a responsive full screen video menu. Here's an image to what it looks like at the moment: [image: imgur]

I'm talking about the bottom right tile. There are two icons, in an achor-tag which again are wrapped in a seperate div. My problem is, that one of those icons isn't clickable because of a div overlay. I thought that this might be solved by giving both the div's and the anchor tags a position and a z-index value.
Unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem as the f-button is still not clickable.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="sm_tile sm_fb menu-item">
  <div class="tcvpb_background_center">
    <a href="http://facebook.com" title="fb">
      <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
    </a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="sm_tile sm_vm menu-item">
  <div class="tcvpb_background_center">
    <a href="http://vimeo.com" title="vm">
      <i class="fa fa-vimeo"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

After positioning my div's:

```
.tcvpb_background_center {
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
}

.sm_vm .tcvpb_background_center {
    transform: translate(-65%);
}
.sm_fb .tcvpb_background_center {
    transform: translate(-35%);
}
```

I give my links a pos: rel as well as a z-index of 1:

```
#menu-main-menu .menu-item .sm_tile a {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    position:relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

The right button remains unclickable unfortunately and even though I looked into other z-index issues I can't seem  to resolve mine.
Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: What'st he purpose of the overlay? Seems like your layout is more complex than it needs to be. Describe the goal.

Comment: @TrevorClarke Both these letters are links, while the left one is clickable, the right one isn't. Even though it has a higher z-index than it's parent div.

Comment: @isherwood I'm looking to build a responsive full screen video menu. Here's an image to what it looks like at the moment: [imgur](http://i.imgur.com/OTuMSzE.jpg)
I need the overlay to position those links in a correct way. I know that there might be other solutions but I'm really just looking for a way to solve it using this one.

Comment: Edit your question to describe the goal, please. Don't add new information in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your links are in surrounding elements that both use this class:

```
.tcvpb_background_center {
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

So both of them have 100% width and they are at the same vertical position (top: 50%), therefore they are on top of each other, meaning that the vimeo link's container covers the facebook link's container, making it not clickable. Use the browser's developer tools, there you see it.

Assign these containers different classes that don't have 100% width and are placed next to each other.

Answer (score 1):

replace div with span as such

```
<a href="my link"><img  class="" src="my_image" alt="">
<span class="rig-overlay"></span>
<span class="rig-text">
<span>name</span>
<span>function</span>
</span>
</a>
```

the span will not cover the clickable region

Answer (score 0):

instead of you complex css + html.
my suggestion is to use much cleaner DOM:

```
<div style="display:flex; padding:10px">
  <a style="flex:1" href="http://facebook.com" title="fb">f</a>
  <a style="flex:1" href="http://vimeo.com" title="vm">v</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Oron. But I wasn't looking for a way to implement my menu using flexbox. I'm only looking for a way to get the "f" clickable using my current markup. Still, much appreciated.

Comment: Hi NP :) please update your JSFiddle so that the output will be more clear, and I will be happy to help you.